# One Click Hyperlink in Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way in Google spreadsheets to reach a url with just one click?
right Now you need 2 clicks. The first click gives you the option to edit or to goto the link.  I want for certain users it goes directly to the link.

```
=HYPERLINK(A3;"Uren registratie (PZ) ")
```

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the only solution would be to publish your spreadsheet to a webpage. When you view the links from web-link they are single-clickable.

[This Google Help forum about single click links](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/CyPBmkvWhrc) addresses the solution which suggests publishing your GoogleSheet as a webpage. It's not pretty, but it works. The drawback is the spreadsheet isn't editable from that shared link.

Comment: That's not an article, it's a link to a help forum. Did you mean to link to the article in the chosen answer? Either way, you should update your answer to add a relevant snippet from the destination link in case your linked item is deleted, edited, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, I updated the answer to include a snippet as you suggested and changed the link title to not say "article".

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use google docs instead of google sheets. Using the bookmark feature, you can create a continuous stream of information that can jump around from section to section. While as a google doc, this requires two clicks, but you can print your doc to PDF, and your PDF will function the way you're describing, navigating around your information with just one click. Very different formatting requirements, I know, but might be useful.